# C# Regex multi match

Tags: c#, regex

I want (in C#) to check the syntax and extract some data from a string.
Check if the string contains: "`someWord IS someWord( OR someWord){1-infinite}`"
And extract every words and for the first word, name the group "switch"

This is my string :

```
string text = "[bird] IS blue OR yellow OR green";
```

So I use this regex

```
string switchPattern = @"\s*(?<switch>.+?)\s+IS\s+(.+?)(?:\s+OR\s+(.+?))+$";
```

And extract with

```
Match switchCaseMatch = Regex.Match(text, switchCaseOperatorPattern);
```

This give me a group with 4 elements

```
[0]: [bird] IS blue OR yellow OR green
[1]: green
[2]: blue
[3]: [bird]  named switch
```

but I want

```
[0]: [bird] IS blue OR yellow OR green
[1]: green
[2]: yellow
[3]: blue
[4]: [bird]  named switch
```

I hoped that the last "`(.+?)`" will create a group for all matching cases, but it create only one, for the last occurence. I try with `Regex.Matches` with the same result.

I know that I could do it with two regex (a Regex.Match then Regex.Matches for the "`someWord( OR someWord){1-infinite}`"), but I want to know if is it possible to do it with only one regex.

Thanks

Comment: considering your given string , what is your expected result ?

Comment: `Regex.Captures` instead of `Regex.Groups` might give you what you want. See [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you can do it with `Regex.Match`, using `Captures` as I said in my comment. Here is a code sample:

```
        string text = "[bird] IS blue OR yellow OR green";
        string switchPattern = @"\s*(?<switch>.+?)\s+IS\s+(.+?)(?:\s+OR\s+(.+?))+$";

        Match switchCaseMatch = Regex.Match(text, switchPattern);
        foreach (Group group in switchCaseMatch.Groups)
        {
            if (group.Captures.Count == 1)
                Console.WriteLine(group.Value);
            else foreach (Capture cap in group.Captures)
                    Console.WriteLine(cap.Value);
        }
```

This results in:

```
[bird] IS blue OR yellow OR green
blue
yellow
green
[bird]
```

See the [Microsoft MSDN page for Captures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information

Comment: Thanks a lot that exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think using groups will be difficult because you need to anticipate how many groups you will have. I suggest using the `Matches` method and `MatchCollection` instead. You'll have access to the named group inside of there as well as capturing all occurrences of the target strings you are after.

e.g.

```
string text = "[bird] IS blue OR yellow OR green";
string switchPattern = @"(?<=(?<switch>\S+)\s+IS.*?)(\w+(?=\s+OR)|(?<=OR\s+)\w+)";
MatchCollection switchCaseMatch = Regex.Matches(text, switchPattern);

foreach (Match m in switchCaseMatch)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["switch"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

You construct the pattern to use an un-bounded lookbehind to search for the `switch` (group) text. This will force every occurrence of a color to follow that text. The dot-star in that lookbehind will consume all color texts that have been captured in previous iterations. Then, you use either a lookahead to find the first color (by ensuring that "OR" follows the color) or a lookbehind to find all subsequent colors (by ensuring the "OR" precedes the color. Then it's just a matter of evaluating the `Value` property of each `Match` object in the `MatchCollection`. The named group will be captured in each `Match` so you'll have access to that as well.

Comment: You can do it using `Regex.Match`, by using the `Captures` property within a `Group`...see my comment and answer for more info.

Comment: Yeah, I got ya. I haven't used `Captures` much, but OP was trying to use `Groups` which I was pretty sure wouldn't work.